# android stop service and run service just once time

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm trying to stop my service but I can't, I don't know why.
And one more question : how can I run service class just for one time ? means one class service if runs for second time don't restart or start again.
Thanks for your attention-
my code :

I use :

```
intent = new Intent(G.context, MyService.class);
G.context.stopService(intent);
```

In myservice class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  MediaPlayer          myMediaPlayer;
  MediaPlayer          myMediaPlayer2;
  public ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
  public SensorManager mSensorManager;
  public Sensor        mAccelerometer;
  public boolean       shake = true;
  Handler              handler;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    handler = new Handler();
    Log.e("LOG", "Service Start");

    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyService.this,
            R.raw.play3);

    myMediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(MyService.this,
            R.raw.play1);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake() {
            myMediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    myMediaPlayer.pause();
    myMediaPlayer2.pause();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, new Handler());

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Comment: `START_NOT_STICKY` is probably what you want so the service isn't recreated once it is finished.  Any reason why the `handler` object cannot stop the service after it's finished?

Comment: no my service is run and when shake phone run againe and againe

Comment: Move the handler to `onStart`